# Are we crystals?

Tags: solid-state-physics, material-science, definition

Can we say that we are crystals because just like crystals we are made up of very small unit (cell) making up almost the same shape (our body) everywhere.

Comment: Crystals are solids. But "we" are solid and liquid and gas. So no. There are many repeating patterns in Nature however.

Comment: @Roy given the recent advances in material science, it wouldn't come as much of a surprise to discover a crystalline material which nevertheless behaves as a fluid. @LifeH2O one *could* say that a human body is a "crystal", if one were to stretch the conventional definition of a crystalline object to cover semi-regular objects such as organic tissue. But even then, it would be pushing it. Perhaps you have a more specific question in mind?

Comment: @Deepak ""it wouldn't come as much of a surprise to discover a crystalline material which nevertheless behaves as a fluid. "" This non-surprise experience was made by a certain Prof Lehmann about 150 years ago. Since then liquid crystals are well-known, since the late 1960ties a lot of use is made of them for displays. Maybe You look at a liquid crystal display right now.

Comment: @Georg, well, yes. In my defense, I was thinking of something a little more macroscopic. But, good point.

Comment: @Deepak Vaid : Actually I wonder if any Stack users are bots (c.f. Jeopardy). In that case the "we" of a question like this refers to the crystalline silicon of said bots.

Comment: @Roy Simpson LOL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

Of course, to argue if a definition applies, we must first agree on a definition. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal) gives this one:

> A crystal or crystalline solid is a
>   solid material whose constituent
>   atoms, molecules, or ions are arranged
>   in an orderly repeating pattern
>   extending in all three spatial
>   dimensions.

Humans are certainly solid-ish, and our constituent molecules are arranged in a somewhat orderly pattern in all three dimensions. However, I think we fail the 'repeating' portion of this definition. If you want to use a more broad definition of a crystal, link to it.

Finally, supposing the answer was 'yes'. What are the practical predictions which follow from this assertion? We certainly don't diffract x-rays into a regular grid, for example.

Comment: The interesting question is that can life exist in the form of crystals?

Comment: @Anna, the only way to act "lifelike" for a crystal is to act as a seed crystal when growing new ones. Al other essentials to life (eg metabolism) I can't imagine with crystals

Answer (score 4):

Certainly not. Crystals by definition have some translation invariant lattice structure and humans do not.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is No, we are not crystals by any definition of crystal.

What I think you are asking though can be answered in a larger set of definitions, which includes crystals. *" A quantum mechanical state function exists and in principle could be found which mathematically describes crystals and can predict their appearance and  interactions" .*

In this sense, one can *aim* at finding a quantum mechanical state function describing parts of the living body, neurons for example, or cells in general. In principle it should exist, in practice I do not think anybody has reached that point. People are working with chemical potentials etc, which are a meta level to the underlying quantum mechanical state functions which are  there.